# Compare multiple columns of excel with one column having different length and index

Tags: python, excel, pandas

how do I compare the excel using python pandas?

For eg.

```
  A    B    C  D  E  F
1     3,4   
2     1,2
3     4,4
4     5,5
5
6     TBC1  TBC2  TBC3
7     1, 4  3,4   2, 1
8     1,1   1, 3  1, 2
9     3,1   4,4   4,2
10    2,4   5,5   5,1
11   
12    TBC4  TBC5  TBC6
13    1, 4  3,4   3, 4
14    1,1   1, 2  1, 2
15    1, 3  3,2   4,4
16    2,3   1, 4  5,5
17
```

TBC- To be compare

How do i compare B1-4 to eat set for eg B7 to B10

Please advise

Comment: What is the desired output as you wanted? maybe you should split the excel to 2 or 3 dataframe use `iloc`, or `loc` first.

Comment: Actually the TBC1 to 3 is one dataframe with different set and TBC 4 to 6 is another. So is like DNA Comparison The top data is a child dna while TBC1-3 is the male and TBC4-6 is female dna. Outcome is to compare which individual set which matches with the top child dna. Ultimately, desired outcome should be TBC 1- 3 [total number of true in each data]